# Infinite loop during file reading and String.split() not working properly

Tags: java, string, loops, file-io, split

I have a text file `admin.dat` which looks like this:

```
blackranger|sdasdasdasd23123|1000
blueranger|sdasdasdasdwhhh22|1000
brownranger|lppsadospd123|1000
```

I am trying to read every line, using `|` as my delimiter and outputting to the console every section.

**Code**:

```
package testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner filereader = null;
        try {
            filereader = new Scanner(new File("./src/testing/players.dat"));
            String data;
            while(filereader.hasNextLine()) {
                String foo = "abc|123|a213";
                String[] bar = foo.split("|");
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    System.out.println(bar[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while reading file");
        } finally {
            if (filereader != null) {
                filereader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Outcome**:

```
blackranger
sdasdasdasd23123
1000
blueranger
sdasdasdasdwhhh22
1000
brownranger
lppsadosph123
1000
```

**Actual Outcome**:

```
a // infinite loop
b


a
b 


a
b


a
b



a
b
```

Why am I getting an infinite loop which prints `a b` forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never read from the fileReader inside the while loop, so `while(filereader.hasNextLine())` will ***always*** be true, and it makes sense that the loop will never end. What surprised me is that it looked like you had code that did read from the fileReader inside of the loop but commented it out. Why?

Solution: don't do this. Make sure to change the test condition inside the while loop, else the while loop will never end.

Answer (score 5):

You should escape the character `|` because it has special meaning in `regex`

```
 foo.split("\\|");
```

But firstly, assign `foo` with value that you read from the file, not by hard-coded it:

```
String foo = filereader.nextLine();
```

Comment: No but i'm 100% that the reason of that array values is, `|` should be escaped

Comment: After your updated answer it will work fine. Before that it wont.

Answer (score 2):

```
String foo = filereader.nextLine();
String[] bar = foo.split("\\|");
```

instead of

```
 String foo = "abc|123|a213";
 String[] bar = foo.split("|");
```